# Bootstrap 3 layout to break out of grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a small issue with Bootstrap where I don't know how to solve it.
Imagine the following 12 column layout:

```
<div class="container">
    ... several other row definitions...

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">A</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">B</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">C</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">D</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">E</div>
    </div>

    ... several other row definitions...
</div>
```

On extra small devices (xs), this will put A to E into full size columns:

```
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| E |
```

That is what I want.

But on small devices (sm) (and any larger devices), I want to put B to D into a row, without width, and break the grid:

```
| A |
| B C D |
| E |
```

Is this possible with bootstrap? Thanks for any hints!

B,C,D itself should not have widths (I could align them in line with a width by setting .col-sm-2 class, but I don't want it with a fixed width), they only should together (as a row) be a full width (12 columns).

Comment: I imagine this is one of the main issues why bootstrap 4 enables [flexbox grid](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/). With flexbox it's a simple matter of assigning them all as one col in `.col-sm`. However, I'm not sure desired behavior/how you're addressing the columns adding up to 12 on large displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution - but I don't recommand it:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">A</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">B</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">C</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">D</div>
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-12">B C D</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">E</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another solution with Javascript:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row break-sm">
        <div class="col-xs-12">B</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">C</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">E</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript (supposing you use Jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(this).width() < 768) {
            $('.break-sm').children('div').addClass('col-xs-12');
            $('.break-sm').children('div').removeClass('inline');
        } else {
            $('.break-sm').children('div').removeClass('col-xs-12');
            $('.break-sm').children('div').addClass('inline');
        }
    });
});
```

The `inline` class should contain something like `display: inline-block;` and other stuff you want.

Comment: I thought about a similiar solution, too, but from a SEO perspective the duplicate content is not good. But at the end, it is a solution that will work, thank you for that.

Comment: Yes, this is why I would not recommand it... You could also use Javascript and watch for the window resize event. If it's becomming smaller than a small device, you can change the CSS and apply the style you want - remove classes or so.

Comment: Just added a piece of code, let me know what you think.

Comment: JS is a way, too, but I like to keep the amount of JS as little as possible. I'll stick with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

So you want B,D,C to have a dynamic width but in total not exceed 100%, right? I don't think that is possible with bootstrap classes only. I'd have to know what width those 3 div's have in order to make a working solution.

You can however "break the grid" by using a container-fluid and and put 3 col-sm-4 in it.
Like this:

http://www.bootply.com/jpt7uAWOBJ

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">A</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">B</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">C</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">D</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">E</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This would do it, unfortunately I cannot add additional container divs as this would break the outer layout.